# Sending data from a form to a http post request but wrong format?

Tags: php, http, curl, post, php-curl

I'm trying to send a post request and this is the correct format

```
https://domainname.com/dashboard/api?to={PHONE NUMBER}&from={SENDER ID}&message={TEXT}&email={YOUR EMAIL}&api_secret={API SECRET}
```

This is how the request should look like:

```
https://domainname.com/dashboard/api?to=123456789&from=text&message=text&email=email@email.com&api_secret=123abc
```

So i made a html form:

```
<div class="body"> 
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div id="form"> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>To: 
                <input type="text" name="to" id="to" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>From: 
                <input type="text" name="from" id="from" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>Message: 
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" /> 
                </label> 
            </div>
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>Email: 
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> 
                </label> 
                <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>Api_Secret: 
                <input type="text" name="api_secret" id="api_secret" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            </div> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </div> 
    </form>
```

And a php file to process the data with curl:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://domainname.com/dashboard/api',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'to' => $_POST['to'],
        'from' => $_POST['from'],
        'message' => $_POST['message'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'api_secret' => $_POST['api_secret'],
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo($response);
?>
```

But it still doesn't work.
I did a request on postbin and the query looks like this:

```
123456789:
text:
text:
email@email.com:
123abc:
```

Is it the wrong format? Am i sending everyhing in a wrong format? 
Help is highly appreciated as i have been messing with this for the past 3 days..

Comment: You are sending POST data. Your example code shows GET data. Are you sure tha API endpoint can consume POST data as well? Looks like the endpoint only consumes GET parameters.

Comment: Oof, im a total noob and im close to having no idea on what im doing... do i have to change my entire code to send a GET request or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **API** seems to **accept GET request not POST**, **your call** with curl **is POST**.

So, your form seems to be ok, they have all the variables needed by API.

Now I think the problem is your index.php file (wich is called from the form), try this:

```
<?php
//checking for all variables filled in form
if (isset($_POST['to']) && isset($_POST['from']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['api_secret'])){
    //rebuild API call
    $_ENDPOINT_CALL = "https://domainname.com/dashboard/api?to={$_POST['to']}&from={$_POST['from']}&message={$_POST['message']}&email={$_POST['email']}&api_secret={$_POST['api_secret']}";

    //cURL GET request
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $_ENDPOINT_CALL
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    //write response
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks again!